# rails 4 with CKEditor - plugin (codesnipet) doesn't work

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ckeditor

I have a problem with adding plugin codesnippet to my ckeditor.

1. I added gem 'ckeditor' to gemfile
2. Next added this to application.js //= require ckeditor/init
3. <%= f.input :body, :as => :ckeditor, :input_html => { :ckeditor => {:toolbar => 'Full'} } %> to my view forms

Then i can use ckeditor. I can for example create div container fill it and back to ckeditor.

My problem appears when i want add codesippet to ckeditor.

1. For use this plugins first i create app/assets/javascripts/ckeditor/config.js file and fill with this:

   ```
   CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    config.language = 'fr';
    config.uiColor = '#AADC6E';};
   ```
2. I download plugin from ckeditor sites with all dependencies and add this files do ckeditor/plugins and off course add config.extraPlugins = 'codesnippet' + others plugins.
3. With this i see icon for codesnippet, i can use it but when i want close this window and continuing i see my ckeditor but i cant click on anything and on all my site is a little white transparent coating - something like this.

This happens for every appear windows in ckeditor. Below i wrtie what i try to do to solve this problem:
1. I try add my base path  like in documentation on https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor

2. I try this solution:

> ```
> in assets/javascripts/application.js
>
> //= require ckeditor_fix        #- add this line
> //= require ckeditor/init
> //= require_tree .
>
> in assets/javascripts create new file ckeditor_fix.js
>
> var CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = '/assets/ckeditor/';
> ```

At least i try turn of turbolinks but still this dont work.
When i deleted ckeditor folder from my app/assets/javascripts my ckedtior work great.

Comment: did you figure this out?  I am trying to set up codesnippet in my rails app but am not having any success.

Comment: unfortunately i didn't found solution and resign with codesnippet in ckeditor.

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead

```
<%= f.cktext_area :body, :ckeditor => {:toolbar => 'Full'} %>
```

Comment: Try restarting the server and reload the page again

Comment: Instead of downloading it from the website follow the steps given in the gem documentation https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor

Comment: I followed this gem documentation, from official website i only download plugins.
This is error from my firebug console:
uncaught exception: [CKEDITOR.resourceManager.add] The resource name "dialog" is already registered.

Line 0